# Aurelia Redirection to the anonymous page or any other page with default access-token without going to login page....?

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-auth

I developing a demo app which is having a login page., By default I am loading to that default page. But For some pages I want to go with the URL directly redirect to that page. But aurelia default loading to the login page. How can I redirect to the anonymous URL or some URL with my token directly without going to Login page.

Can anyone explain me or give a sample ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `canActivate()`

```
canActivate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction) {
  //some check for token in params
  if (hasToken) {
    return new Redirect(`/someroute/${token}`);
  }
  // proceed and load login page
}
```

or you can use different routes like

```
 { route: 'login',  moduleId: './pages/login'},
 { route: 'login/token/:token',  moduleId: './pages/anonym'},
```

Comment: I cannot able to hit the canActivate() method in my loginpage.

Comment: would be nice to see setup of your app files, do you use Login as `appRoot`? If you do, you need to configure child router in Login to handle redirection, note that you also have to switch appRoot when you get token